# SUBSTITUTE FORMULA EXCEL - switching numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to replace a set of numbers 1,2,3,4,5 with the reverse number as part of a calculation that needs to be done.
1=5, 2=4, 3=3, 4=2, 5=1.

The formula i am using is

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F13,"2","4",1 ),"1", "5", 1 ),"4", "2", 1 ),"5", "1", 1 ),"2","4", 1)
```

However, it is only working for numbers 2 and 5 and is not substituting 1 and 4.

Comment: could you provide some test data and expected output?

Comment: Are your number just number or do they have `,` like above?

Comment: If you are comfortable with MACRO then Ican suggest you a simple Macro will rewrite contains of the cell in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the replacement on numbers(no text)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((6-MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1))*10^(LEN(A1)-ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))))
```

[image]

It just iterates the number subtracting each part from 6 to get the flipped number and then multiplies it by a factor of 10 to put in the correct order.

---

It gets a little more complicated with strings.  we can use an array version of CONCAT, which was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

```
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)),6-MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

This too iterates the string and if it is a number it subtracts from 6 and puts back with the concat.

---

If you want to continue with nested SUBSTITUTES, then you need to change two of the numbers to something else before switching the other two.  Then switch the special characters to the desire output.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,"!"),2,"@"),4,2),5,1),"@",4),"!",5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful! I got it to work with the adjusted SUBSTITUTE formula.

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Write this Array formula in Cell `B2`:*

```
{=RIGHT(SUM(VALUE(MID(A2&"1",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2&"1"))),1))*10^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2&"1")))-1)),LEN(A2))}
```

**Note,** finish the formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

**For comma separated list of numbers/text Copy & Paste the below written VBA code as Module with the Sheet.**

```
Function ReverseTxt(ByVal Target As Range)
    myLength = Len(Target.Value)
    For x = 0 To myLength
        ReverseTxt = Left(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Target.Value, Left(Target.Value, x), ""), 1) & ReverseTxt
    Next x
End Function
```

Write the UDF in Cell `B4` & fill down: `=ReverseTxt(A2)`

**N.B.**

- Above shown UDF is suitable for single digit/character list.
- If you try the UDF for `12, 13` then will be `31, 21` & `DA` will `AD`.